# How do I make use of SpeechRecognitionEngine in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, speech-recognition, msdn

I am making a windows phone application in which I need to take input as a wav file as default using System.Speech.Recognition Namespace.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Speech.Recognition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wrong class, you need to use Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition.  Use the [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Speech-recognition-and-debe5858) to get started correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, but in this link(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile(v=vs.110).aspx) in platforms section its written windows phone too. How can I use it?